# Do stuff after responding a html petition

Tags: php, web-services, web

Thats a scheme of my question:

Structure:

```
Client      ServerA      ServerB
```

Both ServerA and ServerB offer a REST Web Service (php and mysql). And what I'm looking for is:

```
Client  (queries)-------> ServerA
   |                         |
   |                         |
   |                         V
   | <------------(response)-*-(queries) -----> Server B
//Client's petition          |                      |
 is finished                 |                      |
                             v                      v
                    markAsSent(petition)<------------
              //if the petition fails, retry periodically
```

The server B only stores statistical data and is not needed for answer the client so I want to avoid the client wait the ServerA-to-ServerB petition delay.

How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the answer into a queue table in the database and then immediately return to the user.
Then, have server B asynchronously poll the queue (grab a row) and do whatever statistical processing you need.

Most likely you'll just make server B run a `cron` job which runs a script that fetches & deletes a row out of the queue and processes it.